# Safari ignores stylesheet hierarchy

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I'm trying to figure out why the font stylings are completely different on Google Chrome versus Safari on this page: http://brokencartons.com/category.jhtm?cid=90. Chrome reads my stylesheets as I want it to, but Safari just seems to ignore `how-it-works.css` if you take a look with the inspector. Any idea on why this happens and how I can fix it?

This is what it looks like in Chrome (as I would like it to look like on all browswers):
[image]

This is what it looks like in Safari:
[image]

Comment: While I can't say for certain what's causing this, Safari *really* doesn't like your how-it-works stylesheet: https://cldup.com/O-12RF3TXE.png. It may be as simple as cleaning up these compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try cleaning it up and let you know what happens.